# Which timer to use for GUI in Java

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have been trying to find the best timer to use for the following code (note this is a simplified version of my overall program). My hope is to run a method after 3 seconds.
The problem is with the `actionPerformed`, `checkBlankLogin`, and `resetLoginBlank` and putting a timer to delay `resetLoginBlank` from happening 3 seconds after `checkBlankLogin` has happened. But I want all methods in the class `Outerframe` to continuously run. So `checkBlankLogin` will keep checking if its blank until the person inputs the information for a `"Valid Input"` and the Login `innerframe` will close. But I don't know how to do that... Any help there also?

```
     import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.*;
   import javax.swing.*;
   import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
   import javax.swing.event.*;
   import java.io.*;
    import java.io.File;
   import java.util.*;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

  class OuterFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {
Container pane; // container
JDesktopPane outframe; // outer frame
JInternalFrame login; // login frame
//pieces of login frame
    JLabel loginLBLtitle;
    JPanel loginPanel;
    JLabel loginLBLname;
    JLabel loginBlankName;
    JLabel loginLBLpass;
    JLabel loginBlankPass;
    JTextField loginTXT;
    JPasswordField loginPASS;
    JButton loginBUT;
JInternalFrame apple;



OuterFrame()
{
    //set up for Outer Frame
    super("Application");
    setSize(450,240);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    outframe = new JDesktopPane();
    outframe.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    //set up for Container
    pane = getContentPane();  
    setContentPane(pane);
    pane.add(outframe);


    //Login Inner Frame
    login = new JInternalFrame();
    login.setSize(400,200);
    login.setLocation(20,20);
    login.setTitle("Member Login");
    loginLBLtitle = new JLabel("Sign in with netid and your password.");
    Font loginFontbody = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    Font loginFonthead = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 13);
    loginLBLtitle.setFont(loginFonthead);
    loginLBLname=new JLabel("User Name:");
    loginLBLname.setFont(loginFontbody);
    loginLBLpass=new JLabel("Password:  ");
    loginLBLpass.setFont(loginFontbody);
    loginBUT=new JButton("Login");
    loginBUT.setFont(loginFontbody);
    loginBUT.addActionListener(this);        
    loginTXT=new JTextField(20);
    loginPASS=new JPasswordField(20);
    loginBlankName=new JLabel("");
    loginBlankPass=new JLabel("");
    loginPanel=new JPanel();
    loginPanel.add(loginLBLtitle);
    loginPanel.add(loginLBLname);
    loginPanel.add(loginTXT);
    loginPanel.add(loginBlankName);
    loginPanel.add(loginLBLpass);
    loginPanel.add(loginPASS);
    loginPanel.add(loginBlankPass);
    loginPanel.add(loginBUT);
    //panel.add(lblmess);
    login.add(loginPanel);
    login.setVisible(true);
    //Add Login to Outer Frame
    outframe.add(login);
    outframe.setSelectedFrame(login);
    pane.add(outframe, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setVisible(true);
    loginTXT.requestFocus();

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    //problem area
    if(e.getSource()==loginBUT)
    {
        String uname=loginTXT.getText();
        String passw=new String(loginPASS.getPassword());
        int i=0;
        while(i!=5)
        {
            if(checkBlankLogin(uname,passw,loginBlankName,loginBlankPass))
            {
                resetLoginBlank(loginBlankName,loginBlankPass);
            }
            else
            {

            if(!validateUser("accounts.txt",uname,passw,loginLBLtitle))
                {

            }
        }
    }                   
}
public void resetLoginBlank(JLabel loginBlankName, JLabel loginBlankPass)
{
    loginBlankName.setText("");
    loginBlankPass.setText("");
}
public void resetLoginTitle(JLabel loginBlankTitle)
{
    loginBlankTitle.setText("Sign in with netid and your password.");
    loginBlankTitle.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
}
public boolean checkBlankLogin(String name, String passw, JLabel loginBlankName, JLabel loginBlankPass)
{
    boolean isBlank=false;
    if(name.length()<1)
    {
        loginBlankMess("User name is required.",loginBlankName);
        isBlank=true;
    }
    if(passw.length()<1)
    {
        loginBlankMess("Password is required.",loginBlankPass);
        isBlank=true;
    }
    return isBlank;
}
public void loginBlankMess(String mess, JLabel lbl)
{
    lbl.setText(mess);
    lbl.setForeground(Color.RED);                
}
public boolean validateUser(String filename, String name, String password, JLabel title)
{
        boolean valid = false;

    try
    {
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        ArrayList<String> fileInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            fileInfo.add(line);
        }
        String fullLogin = name + " " + password;
        if(fileInfo.contains(fullLogin))
        {
            //loginBlankMess("Valid login",namemess);
            valid=true;
        }
        if(!valid)
        {
            loginBlankMess("Please enter valid netid and password.", title);
            resetLoginTitle(title);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ie)
    {
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return valid;
}
  }

   public class TheProgram
  {
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    new OuterFrame();
} 
  }`
```

Comment: What choices have you considered?

Comment: So, I can type in a blank name and password.  You might want to change your tests to name.trim().length() < 1 and passw.trim().length() < 1

Comment: Gilbert - What is the advantage of using trim() there?
And I don't think this was clear but "password is required" and "user name is required" are two messages that pop up when the user clicks the button "Login" when two other text fields (Username and Password) are blank. My hope is for these messages to only pop up for 3 seconds and then go away.

Comment: You say `"resetLoginBlank" method is being called from a method that is in the "actionPerformed" method` what do you mean by that?

Comment: @LefterisE I posted the code ^^

Comment: what is the purpose of `while(i!=5)`? if the check for a blank login succeeded the first time, it won't change 5 pico-seconds later.

Answer (score 3):

I would check out the following resource (assuming you using Swing for your UI):

[How to Use Swing Timers (Oracle)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: I was using this website for some information but for my specific condition (needing a timer in a method that is being called from another method that is called from the "actionPerformed" method), it wasn't too helpful

Answer (score 2):

Swing timers are the easiest in your case. You make your class implement ActionListener, and create a timer object. The timer will call the actionPerformed method when it expires.

```
import javax.swing.Timer;

class OuterFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   Timer timer = null;

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==loginBUT){
            //If the action came from the login button
            if (checkBlankLogin()){
               timer = new Timer(3000, this);
               timer.setRepeats(false);
               timer.setInitialDelay(3000);
               timer.start(); 
            } else if (timer != null){
               timer.stop();
            }
        }else if(e.getSource()==timer){
            //If the action came from the timer
            resetLoginBlank(namemess,passwmess));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, as the "resetLoginBlank" method is being called from a method that is in the "actionPerformed" method.

Comment: @user2518777 do you mean you want to call resetLoginBlank from within checkBlankLogin and not actionPerformed?

Comment: look up to the original question for updated information please

Comment: and what do I put in place of pause?

Comment: the number of miliseconds till the next trigger 3000